# Return Multiple Rows from Nothing in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, recursive-query

In Oracle SQL Developer I can use:

```
select level as col1
    , sysdate as col2 
from dual 
connect by level < 5;
```

..to return 4 rows with col1 counting from 1 to 4 and col2 being current date, without selecting from a table.

How can I accomplish this in SQL Server?

Edit: My intent is to return more than 1 row without selecting from a table.  Return values are not important.

Comment: it Depends on what you want to get?  Use Master Database if no Database added.   Try `select SYSDATETIME() as Date` without adding Table Name.

Comment: i Got you, Try `select SYSDATETIME() as Date` and you will get a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server you could typically do that with a recursive common table expression:

```
with cte as (
    select 1 as col1, getdate() as col2
    union all select col1 + 1, col2 from cte where col1 < 4
)
select * from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e23bce1c79f969e607dac913fa647a6f)**:

```
col1 | col2               
---: | :------------------
   1 | 20/12/2019 17:28:37
   2 | 20/12/2019 17:28:37
   3 | 20/12/2019 17:28:37
   4 | 20/12/2019 17:28:37
```